# How to edit program-info.plist item names?

Tags: xcode, ios7.1, info-plist

hello I want to create  this type of array in my info plist[image]

I want to create a new row called URL types and set its type to array. I did it. and I want to create asub array called URL Schemes inside that URL Typrs array. But when I add items under URL Types it only shows as item0, item 1 and I cant edit the title, also item type is dictionary and cant make it into array type too.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Arrays don't have "titles" (keys) so "Item n" is pretty much the only way to describe each entry.  However you then talk about dictionaries and your question then becomes confusing.

Comment: Can u see this picture,, I want to create the URL types array like this, It has another array called URL schemes. So how can I create this URL types array

Comment: Sorry I'm still none the wiser.

Answer (score 0):

If u want to add an item to an array u need to click at the left arrow of the added item (so the array is pointing down) in this case in URL types and than add a new item to it.